# How does the Date() in javascript work?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse "NINE/MAR/2008" using Date function in JS as:

```
new Date("NINE/MAR/2008")
```

This is giving me result as:

> Sat Mar 01 2008

What logic does the date parsing in JS consider?

Comment: Have you tried `new Date("NINE/MAR/TWOTHOUSANDEIGHT")`? On a serious note, `Date` function has limited intelligence for understanding given formats. It obviously doesn't understand your `NINE`.

Comment: Check this [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 4):

The **only** formats that the `Date` constructor and `Date.parse` are required by the specification to support are:

1. The one [introduced by ECMAScript 5th edition](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) in 2009 such as `2015-04-29`, which was meant to be a simplified version of [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) but they messed up on timezones ([fixed in ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format), but then had to be amended *again* in [ECMAScript 2016](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)), and
2. Whatever `Date#toString` outputs on that JavaScript engine (which is not specified).

Most JavaScript engines will also parse `mm/dd/yyyy` (where those are all numbers — always in U.S. format, month-first), but that is **not** specified behavior. Some may parse `yyyy/mm/dd` (note the `/` rather than `-`), but again it's undefined behavior, and in particular some engines may interpret it as UTC and others as local time (and it matters, even if it's just a date without a time on it).

All other date parsing has to be done by your own code or code in a library that you use, such as MomentJS. You can build a `Date` from its constituent parts using the [long form of the constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms), e.g.: `new Date(2008, 2, 9)` for 9th March, 2008 (note that months start with 0 = January).