# JavaScript: Date difference result in two browser are different

Tags: javascript

I am getting two different dates. How can I get difference between two dates?
Dates are in d.m.y format. eg: `11.10.18 & 13.10.18`

```
var dateOne   = new Date('11.10.18');
console.log(dateOne);
var dateTwo   = new Date('13.10.18');
var timeDiff  = Math.abs(dateTwo.getTime() - dateOne.getTime());
var diffDays  = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

On Chrome console, result is correct.

`Sat Nov 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

On Firefox console, error is getting.

`Invalid Date`

Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: The Chrome result isn't correct, since 11.10. is Oct 11, not Nov 10.

Comment: Please search thoroughly before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching). **Every** possible question about parsing dates with JavaScript has been repeated asked and answered. ;-)  Examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876348/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776970/javascript-convert-string-to-date-time) The `Date` constructor isn't specified to parse that format; you have to parse it yourself (with your own code, or a library).

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you. I updated my question.

Comment: @samsam Changing the console result you copy pasted here is nonsense, my point is that Chrome *does not parse a German date correctly, as evident by the console output*, so you need to parse it manually anyway. Chrome parses the second date as `Invalid Date` because it assumes 13.10. is the tenth day of the 13th month.

Comment: It is because firefox is taking dates as MM/DD/YYYY and giving error on 13/10/2018

Comment: @Amitchauhan, Thank you. Any library or built in function for JavaScript to convert this?

Comment: It's  similar to second case in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33299764/7404943), just change separator to `.` and change year to long format

Comment: @Samsam I've Updated my answer and you do not require any external Js for the conversion

Comment: @Amitchauhan, Thank you. But input year is `18` not `2018`. Getting dates like `var dateOne = 11.10.18`; `var dateTwo = 13.10.18`;

Comment: @Samsam 11.10.18 also working, see my updated answer and run the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working perfectly in chrome and giving result as expected
Make your date as  in the format of MM/dd/YYYY before passing to date constructor

```js
var dateOneString = "11.10.18";
var dateTwoString = "13.10.18";
var dateOneSplitted = dateOneString.split('.');
var dateTwoSplitted = dateTwoString.split('.');
var dateOne = new Date("20"+dateOneSplitted[2], dateOneSplitted[1]-1, dateOneSplitted[0]);
var dateTwo = new Date("20"+dateTwoSplitted[2], dateTwoSplitted[1]-1, dateTwoSplitted[0]);

var timeDiff = Math.abs(dateTwo.getTime() - dateOne.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
console.log("Days Difference - "+diffDays);
console.log("Date One - "+dateOne);
console.log("Date Two - "+dateTwo);
```

Comment: Use numbers instead of strings.

Comment: This question is essentially about parsing `'11.10.18'` into a `Date`, and your answer doesn't even attempt to address this.

Comment: @ChrisG I have Updated the answer which is fulfilling the requirements of the author

Comment: @Amitchauhan, I tested your answer. A problem currently I am facing is, When I print `console.log(dateOne)` the result showing in browser is `Mon Nov 11 1918 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`.

Comment: My mistake i forgot that in date contructor we have to provide the month from 0 instead of 1 i.e. it is showing Nov instead of Oct. I've Updated the answer please check

Comment: @samsam Look at the Updated Answer and Run Code snippet

Comment: @Amitchauhan, Thank you.